# Reporting Services: how to set extra properties of dataset fields?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm creating RDLC reports using the visual studio report designer.

In the Visual Studio Report Designer, when editing a RDLC file, I see that in the expression editor there are several style/formatting properties tied to each field of a dataset, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

for example: `BackgroundColor`, `FontSize`, etc.

My question is... how do I provide values for those properties, so that I can use them in the report?
I'm using a `DataTable` C# object to provide the data to the report, but how do I set some of those extra properties??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set these extended field properties but you can read them if they are supported by your data source.

`Value` and `IsMissing` properties are defined for all data sources.

Other properties such as `Key` and `ParentUniqueName` are supported only by a restricted number of data sources (i.e. [SQL Server Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/extended-field-properties-for-an-analysis-services-database-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#predefined-field-properties)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know if there is an in-code data source (something similar to the `DataTable` class) that supports this? Or is it only "real" databases that support it?